# ASP.NET Routing - HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've looked through a ton of the other questions but can't find solution.

Working on something at a new company that requires me to use ASP.NET, I'm coming from a Laravel PHP world where the routing is somewhat similar so the ASP.NET routing doesn't feel to alien.

I'm trying to setup my basic pages for the new site and get the routes going first, here's what I have:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Root",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "About",
            url: "about-us",
            defaults: new { controller = "About", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { }
        );
    }
```

In Laravel this I similar to what I would do apart from the default route isn't required.

In my header view I have a basic navigation:

```
 <ul>
     <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Root")">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("About")">About Us</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I have a AboutController file an an index file within Views/About.

The home / route works fine, but the /about-us URL returns:

```
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /about-us
```

Whats my mistake here? If going to a URL I haven't registered a route to then I get a different 404 error so I at least the route is being picked up.

If I change the controller for my About route to the Home controller it does't return an error.

This is the AboutController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace leadstream.co.uk.Controllers
{
    public class AboutController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The code you have shown works fine so its something else causing the issue. Are you using Areas?

Comment: Hey, i've just deleted the controller and then created it by right clicking the controllers folder and adding it that way. Its now working.

Do I have to do this every time? Last time I just copied the content over, is there something going on in the background when using VS to create the controller that I can do manually? @StephenMuecke

Comment: No, its fine to create it manually (and I tested your code by copy and paste into my project)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Strange! I've also found a link to compile the controllers within the .csproj fie.